Lexical editor: Intercept nodes before inserting them (clipboard)
I am using some Lexial plugin that enhances the copy/paste experience (CopyPasteEnhancementPlugin).
When investigating how it works I found this helper function inside clipboard.ts. The function gets called each time the user pastes some content into Lexical:
export function $insertGeneratedNodes(
  editor: LexicalEditor,
  nodes: Array<LexicalNode>,
  selection: BaseSelection,
): void {
  if (
    !editor.dispatchCommand(SELECTION_INSERT_CLIPBOARD_NODES_COMMAND, {
      nodes,
      selection,
    })
  ) {
    selection.insertNodes(nodes);
  }
  return;
}

I need to intercept the nodes before they get inserted into the selection. E.g. I want to  transform the text so all &nbsp; get replaced with " ". Or certain words get replaced with some arbitrary text string and so on.
What would be the correct way to do this?

I am doing the cleanup of the text at another place now.
I am hooking into the code after the "..." inside clipboard.ts with my function "traverseAndCleanup":
/**
 * Traverses the DOM from a root node and cleans up the text content of all text nodes.
 *
 * @param node a DOM node
 */
const traverseAndCleanup = (node: Node):void => {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      if (node.nodeValue) {
        node.nodeValue = cleanup(node.nodeValue);
      }
  }
  node.childNodes.forEach(child => traverseAndCleanup(child));
}

....
if (htmlString) {
    try {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

      traverseAndCleanup(dom);
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
      return $insertGeneratedNodes(editor, nodes, selection);
    } catch {
      // Fail silently.
    }
  }

